# Best way to enter complex table to sqlite database

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I have some kind of this table. 
[image]

The question is what is the best way to create this kind of table? 
Should I create for each item one table is it possible to create only one table??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: See comments under @Emil.

You should have 1 tables as @Emil has suggested.

This should look like, soemthing like
`_id`, `sort`, `grade`, `diameter`, `length`, `price1_dol`, `price1_euros`, `price2_dol`, `price2_euros`, `final`,

**Note:** I have split up prices columns up - so you have `price1_dol`, `price1_euros`, `price2_dol`, `price2_euros`.

Comment: I created only one table. but can I ask you what would be the best way to populate this table?
I'll have for about 70 rows

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to make this data into just one table. The columns `sort` and `grade` seem to uniquely identify one row so together they might make up a [candidate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key). If so you could use those as your primary key, or create a new integer column that you use as the primary key.

You should definitely not create one table per item. The database schema should never change with normal use. Only when you add, remove or change the *type* of data you have in your database should you consider changing the schema. Otherwise you should design and [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database in such a way that it's possible to grow the data only by inserting new rows, not new tables.

Comment: The columns 'sort' and 'grade' do not uniquley identify a single row, you still have multiple prices, grades etc. - see answer below.

Comment: Zain, show me which two rows have the same `sort, grade` tuple.